# Map keys in all modes?

Tags: evil, spacemacs

Is there a way to bind keys across all modes? For example I have one binding:

```
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "gt") 'persp-next)
```

This works fine in some modes, but not in others, like org-mode, where you have to add a specific binding:

```
  (evil-define-key 'normal org-mode-map (kbd "gt") 'persp-next)
```

This works, but it's annoying to have to define bindings for every major-mode. The final option, global bindings, doesn't seem to work at all without accelerator keys:

```
   (global-set-key (kbd "gt") 'persp-next)
```

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution would be to use [`key-chord-mode`](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/28/execute-commands-ninja-style-with-key-chord-mode/) and the function in that mode: `key-chord-define-global`.

With this mode, once you have enabled it with `(key-chord-mode 1)`, you can set a global keybinding like this:

```
(key-chord-define-global "jj" 'helm-projectile-find-file)
```

This is an example that I use personally, but you can of course add your own functions in place of `helm-projectile-find-file`, and replace `"jj"` with your desired key combination (I don't use evil, but I would assume that something like `(key-chord-define-global "gt" 'persp-next)` would work for you). The combinations are case-sensitive too, so `"jj"` is different from `"JJ"`.

This should allow you to set the kind of bindings you want, without using a modifier key like `C-`, `M-`, etc. Here is [a nice video demo](http://emacsrocks.com/e07.html).

Comment: I tried it out, but it didn't seem to work with casing, "gT" would override "gt" for instance. Another issue is that it's global, I don't want the chords to work in insert mode. It also warns on your link that it doesn't work well with evil.

Comment: @flukus ah, that's too bad. Like I said, I didn't test it with evil. Hopefully someone else will have a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

Started such a project here:

https://github.com/andreas-roehler/general-key

It's still alpha, bug-reports welcome anyway.